# MVC dropdown list with json data and chosen

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to populate dropdown list with jsonResult data on a second list 
on change event. That works just fine. But I also want to use chosen on that list, and with that list is empty. It looks like chosen is not picking up list update. I'm pretty new in this so please help

```
First list:
 <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DropDownList("tipopreme_TipOpremeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "PopuniDropOpreme()" })
 </div>
```

Second List:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()))
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult getOpremaPoTipu(int? tipid)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lista = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (tipid != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in db.ModelOpremes.Where(x=>x.TipOpreme_TipOpremeID==tipid))
            {
                lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.PunNaziv, Value = item.ModelOpremeID.ToString()});
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in db.ModelOpremes)
            {
                lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.PunNaziv, Value = item.ModelOpremeID.ToString() });
            }
        }
        return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

```html
Script:

    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    $("#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID").chosen(); 

    function PopuniDropOpreme() {
        var tip = $("#tipopreme_TipOpremeID").val();
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Opremas/getopremapoTipu?selectedValue=" + tip,
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                

            
                $('.ddlProjectvalue').find('option').remove();

                  
                $(data).each(function (index, item) { 
           

                    $("#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
                });
                $("ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID").chosen("destroy").chosen();
            },
            error: function ajaxError(response) {
                alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
            }
        });
    }   
    
</script>
```

Comment: You have to tell Chosen to rebuild/update.

Comment: I did. Chosen("destroy").chosen(); should rebuild it. I also try chosen: updated and nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

You got some errors in your code:

```
- url: "/Opremas/getopremapoTipu?selectedValue=" + tip, //wrong param name
- $('.ddlProjectvalue').find('option').remove(); //wrong id
```

They should be:

```
- url: "/Opremas/getopremapoTipu?tipid=" + tip
- $('#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID').find('option').remove();
```

You can follow my sample. Hope to help, my friend!

```
public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
public JsonResult GetData(int? selectedValue)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lista = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if (selectedValue != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Data().Where(t=>t.Id == selectedValue))
                {
                    lista.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = item.Id.ToString(),
                        Value = item.Value
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Data())
                {
                    lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Id.ToString(), Value = item.Value.ToString() });
                }
            }
            return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private List<Test> Data()
        {
            var data = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test{Id = 1, Value = "A1"},
                new Test{Id = 1, Value = "A2"},
                new Test{Id = 1, Value = "A3"},
                new Test{Id = 1, Value = "A4"},

                new Test{Id = 2, Value = "B1"},
                new Test{Id = 3, Value = "C1"},
                new Test{Id = 4, Value = "D1"},
            };
            return data;
        }
```

And code in View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";    
}

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
</head>
<body style="margin-top:50px;">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            $("#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID").chosen();
            $(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Home/GetData?selectedValue=" + id,
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "Json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID').find('option').remove();                        
                        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                            $("#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Text).html(item.Value));
                        });
                        $("#ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID").chosen("destroy").chosen();
                    },
                    error: function ajaxError(response) {
                        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <select class="chzn-select" name="faculty" style="width:200px; margin:10%;">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="ModelOpreme_ModelOpremeID"  style="width:200px; ">
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```